# only allow form to validate if the regex is true

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, gravity-forms-plugin

The following regex if statement doesn't seem to work. I want to make sure the user enters between 2-3 letters and then between 7 - 11 numbers. otherwise return the error message.

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_1_44', 'tax_id_verif', 10, 4 );
    function tax_id_verif ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) 
    {$tax_regex = "/^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\s?+[1-9]{7,12}$/g";
    $tax_match = preg_match($tax_regex, $value, $match);
    if ($result != $tax_match) {
    $result['is_valid'] = false;
    $result['message'] = 'Please enter a correct tax ID';
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

Comment: The `g` modifier is not supported. Also, `\s?+` matches 1 or 0 whitespaces, maybe you just need `\s*`. Also, `[1-9]` only matches digits from `1` to `9`, it won't match a `0`. Try `$tax_regex = "/^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\s*[0-9]{7,11}$/"`

Comment: `[1-9]` won't match zeros. I think you mean `[0-9]`.

Comment: [1-9]{7,12} will match between 7 and 11 numbers (except 0), maybe you wanted:
`[0-9]{7,11}`
(btw, \d is the same as [0-9])

Comment: What is the content of `$result` and `$value`?

Answer (score 0):

The `g` modifier is not supported by PHP regex. Also, `\s?+` matches 1 or 0 whitespaces, you can use a mere `\s*`. Also, `[1-9]` only matches digits from `1` to `9`, it won't match a `0`.  If you need to match 7 to 1**1** digits, use `{7,11}` and not `{7,12}`.

Use

```
$tax_regex = "/^[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\s*[0-9]{7,11}$/";
```

If there should be no whitespace between letters and digits, remove `\s*`.